# Android comparing time and milliseconds

Tags: android, timestamp

I'm trying to compare time in milliseconds in Android with the system time.
`startDate` and `endDate` are all `long` and represent timestamps in milliseconds.

```
if (startDate <= System.currentTimeMillis()  >= endDate)
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> The operator >= is undefined for the argument type(s) boolean, long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change it to

```
if (startDate <= System.currentTimeMillis() && System.currentTimeMillis() >= endDate)
```

The reason for this is because the statements get evaluated like so:

```
startDate <= System.currentTimeMillis();
<result of above> >= endDate;
```

or equivalently

```
(startDate <= System.currentTimeMillis()) <= endDate
```

The `<=` operator results in a boolean value and then what you have is

```
boolean <= long
```

which you can't do.  Unfortunately in Java, you can't chain operations together like that because they are evaluated one at a time and then the result of the first is used as input to the second, and so on.